# Message when redirected by a hook on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook, action, message

I am using a small code snipet to redirect non logged user from the shop page to the main page.

```
function my_redirect() {  
    //if you have the page id of landing. I would tell you to use if( is_page('page id here') instead
    //Don't redirect if user is logged in or user is trying to sign up or sign in
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('shop')){
        echo 'Non logged user - You are redirected to the main page'; 
        exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink(2604) ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect' );
```

This is working fine.
However I would like to prompt a message saying "You must be log to access the shop".

I don't know how to do it, my echo in the code do not display anything.

Any idea ?

Thx

Comment: You echo your message before the redirect. Also use is_shop() instead of is_page('shop').

Comment: Is this a `get_permalink(2604)`  custom template?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani not sure to undestand your questions. I want to redirect to my main page. 2604 is the ID of this page.

Answer (score 0):

You will never see the output of the echo because this action is triggered just before wordpress decides which template to load, so it's an echo in the middle of nowhere (and why the wp_redirect is inside and exit function?)

Comment: Ok echo is not a good solution.
Is there still a way to display a message after redirect ?

Comment: I think you have to use another hook or event before the redirect